# Using the returned values as an input to the function continuously

Tags: c

I have this code that used KD tree written in C used in searching for nearest neighbor and then uses the returned value to search for the next nearest neighbor from that point. I want to do this for about 5 iterations i.e the result of first iteration is used as an input to the 2nd and the result of the second used for the 3rd etc. I am a beginner and I thought probably do while loop will work but fails after 2 iterations i.e i get the same input again.

How do I change the value of this variable to reflect changes such that the output of first iteration is the input of the last operation been performed. Also if there is a way to create a function for this, it will be highly appreciated. The code works with gcc compiler.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX_DIM 4

struct kd_node_t{
    double x[MAX_DIM];
    struct kd_node_t *left, *right;
};

    inline double
dist(struct kd_node_t *a, struct kd_node_t *b, int dim)
{
    double t, d = 0;
    while (dim--) {
        t = a->x[dim] - b->x[dim];
        d += t * t;
    }
    return d;
}
inline void swap(struct kd_node_t *x, struct kd_node_t *y) {
    double tmp[MAX_DIM];
    memcpy(tmp,  x->x, sizeof(tmp));
    memcpy(x->x, y->x, sizeof(tmp));
    memcpy(y->x, tmp,  sizeof(tmp));
}


/* quickselect method */
    struct kd_node_t*
find_median(struct kd_node_t *start, struct kd_node_t *end, int idx)
{
    if (end <= start) return NULL;
    if (end == start + 1)
        return start;

    struct kd_node_t *p, *store, *md = start + (end - start) / 2;
    double pivot;
    while (1) {
        pivot = md->x[idx];

        swap(md, end - 1);
        for (store = p = start; p < end; p++) {
            if (p->x[idx] < pivot) {
                if (p != store)
                    swap(p, store);
                store++;
            }
        }
        swap(store, end - 1);

        /* median has duplicate values */
        if (store->x[idx] == md->x[idx])
            return md;

        if (store > md) end = store;
        else        start = store;
    }
}

    struct kd_node_t*
make_tree(struct kd_node_t *t, int len, int i, int dim)
{
    struct kd_node_t *n;

    if (!len) return 0;

    if ((n = find_median(t, t + len, i))) {
        i = (i + 1) % dim;
        n->left  = make_tree(t, n - t, i, dim);
        n->right = make_tree(n + 1, t + len - (n + 1), i, dim);
    }
    return n;
}


int visited;

void nearest(struct kd_node_t *root, struct kd_node_t *nd, int i, int dim,
        struct kd_node_t **best, double *best_dist)
{
    double d, dx, dx2;

    if (!root) return;
    d = dist(root, nd, dim);
    dx = root->x[i] - nd->x[i];
    dx2 = dx * dx;

    visited ++;

    if (!*best || d < *best_dist) {
        *best_dist = d;
        *best = root;
    }


    nearest(dx > 0 ? root->left : root->right, nd, i, dim, best, best_dist);
    if (dx2 >= *best_dist) return;
    nearest(dx > 0 ? root->right : root->left, nd, i, dim, best, best_dist);
}

int main(void)
{
    int i;

  struct kd_node_t wp[] = {
        {{7, 9, 5, 56}},{{2, 4, 8, 10}},  {{81, 2, 31, 80}}, {{31, 4, 900, 1}},{{4, 7, 1, 9}}, {{9, 6, 2,0}}, {{4, 3, 11, 2}},{{7, 7, 9, 1}}, {{6, 9, 0,2}}
    };

    struct kd_node_t testNode = {{0, 2}}; //This is the input

    struct kd_node_t *root, *found, *million;
    double best_dist;
    double length =sizeof(wp) / sizeof(wp[1]);
    root = make_tree(wp, sizeof(wp) / sizeof(wp[1]), 0, 2);

    visited = 0;
    found = 0;
    nearest(root, &testNode, 0, 2, &found, &best_dist);

    printf(">> WP tree\nsearching for (%g, %g)\n"
            "found (%g, %g %g, %g) dist %g\nseen %d nodes\n\n",
            testNode.x[0], testNode.x[1],
            found->x[0], found->x[1],found->x[2], found->x[3], sqrt(best_dist), visited);
//It produces an output found->x[0], found->x[1], found->x[2], found->x[3]

for(int i=0; i<5; i++) //Where the problem is and where i will like to continuously use the returned value as input
{


    testNode = {{found->x[2], found->x[3]}}; // This is the new input i.e the output of the previous run
printf(" (%g, %g) ",
                found->x[2], found->x[3]);
     root = make_tree(wp, sizeof(wp) / sizeof(wp[1]), 0, 2);
     nearest(root, &testNode, 0, 2, &found, &best_dist);
  printf(">> WP tree\nsearching for (%g, %g)\n"
            "found (%g, %g %g, %g) dist %g\nseen %d nodes\n\n",
            testNode.x[0], testNode.x[1],
            found->x[0], found->x[1],found->x[2], found->x[3], sqrt(best_dist), visited);



}



    return 0;
}
```

This is a sample output from the running code

```
>> WP tree
searching for (0, 2)
found (2, 4 8, 10) dist 2.82843
seen 4 nodes

8 10>> WP tree
searching for (8, 10)
found (7, 9 5, 56) dist 1.41421
seen 11 nodes

5 56>> WP tree
searching for (5, 56)
found (7, 9 5, 56) dist 1.41421
seen 16 nodes

5 56>> WP tree
searching for (5, 56)
found (7, 9 5, 56) dist 1.41421
seen 21 nodes

5 56>> WP tree
searching for (5, 56)
found (7, 9 5, 56) dist 1.41421
seen 26 nodes

5 56>> WP tree
searching for (5, 56)
found (7, 9 5, 56) dist 1.41421
seen 31 nodes
```

In fact 5,56 should return 6, 9,0,2 and the next point to be selected should be 0,2 etc.
Also how do I delete temporarily the value of the returned value from wp so that when it searches, it does not include its coordinate in the search space but at the next iteration, its value should be restored. e.g say I am searching for 5,56; the entire {{7, 9, 5, 56, 30}} will be removed from wp for that current search but will be restored later after returning its nearest data.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The current `nearest()` will only work for the first neighbour. You need to modify it so that you can tell it to ignore certain nodes from being considered as "best". Typically, you do this by adding two more parameters to `nearest()`: an array of pointers to `struct kd_node_t` (or `kd_node_t **ignore`) to identify the points you already have visited, and the number of nodes in that array (`size_t num_ignore` or similar). For the initial search, it will be empty, but you'll add the pointer to each found point to the list for the succeeding searches.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks for your suggestion. I implemented that but it's still not solving the problem and also how do i deal with making it continuous since the for loop isn't working as required? Do you mind writing the code more explicitly?

Comment: As I suspect this is homework, no, I won't write your code for you. I like to help, but that would be counterproductive. It is worth your while and effort to actually get the code working, now that you know how it is done in principle. Finally, I am not good at minimal examples, and tend to rewrite the code from scratch. I'd probably implement the k-d tree differently (using a different node structure; one with dimension index and coordinate value along that dimension)), so even if I did, it might not help you much.

Comment: @NominalAnimal No it's not an assignment. I got the code from rosettacode.org/wiki/K-d_tree#C and I was only trying to play around it to be somewhat robust. However it is taking more time than expected so I had to seek help.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Please can you write it in a form of psuedocode or a rough sketch of how the nearest function that you stated will look like?

Answer (score 1):

In a comment, I stated that the OP needs to modify the code to ignore the already known points.

However, that turns out to be incorrect. A [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) works very well for locating the nearest "mapped" known point to any supplied point. However, trying to ignore mapped points lead to serious complications. A typical result is that your search simply misses some nearest points. This can be corrected for, but it slows down the search, and requires more complex code.

It took me quite a bit of thought and even an example program to find out exactly what happens, when a k-d tree search tries to exclude points in the tree from consideration. Those that are aware of this property of k-d trees are probably laughing at me for not realizing this earlier; it is quite simple when you realize what happens. However, most authors I have found gloss over this, and simply state that the k-d trees are *approximate* nearest neighbour data structures (at least when you wish to ignore specific points in the tree).

So, in the hopes that this might help someone else, here are my thoughts on the matter.

---

First, let's review how a "normal" k-d tree nearest neighbour search works:

- All points are stored in leaf nodes
- Typically a set of points is stored in each leaf node; the size depends on the number of dimensions used. For 3D, I'd start with at least ten vectors per leaf node. Optimum number depends on too many factors for any real guide to be just handwaving.
- Each inner node splits the search volume in half, along one of the axes
- To find the *approximate* nearest neighbour to a test point, a function descends into the tree, always selecting the search volume that contains the test point, until it arrives at a leaf node; there, it finds the point closest to the test point
- To ensure that the neighbour found in the leaf node is the real nearest neighbour, or to find the actual one, a *precise* nearest neighbour search must ascend back towards the root. For each inner node, if the splitting plane (split coordinate) is closer than the distance to the thus far found nearest neighbour, the other subvolume (than we just ascended from) must also be verified.

There are several ways to extend the search to *k*-nearest neighbour.

My original suggestion that one could simply ignore points in the tree that are already known, will occasionally fail, because in cases where a neighbour is found in the leaf node after others have been excluded, we fail to descend into a sibling node because the split plane is too far. Typically, we stumble onto a closer split plane higher up, closer to the root, and descend into *that* subvolume, but to no avail: we have already skipped the subvolumes where the true nearest neighbour was in.

A much better option is to record *all* *k* nearest neighbours, and using the furthest one to decide when not to descend into sibling subvolumes on our way back towards the root. We only need room for the *k* nearest neighbours, sorted according to distance from the test point. This list will be modified along several steps when returning back from the leaf towards the root.

Of course, that does not return the *k*th nearest neighbour, but all *k* nearest neighbours to the test point. Usually, this is preferable. I do not know of efficiency figures (how many leaf nodes must be visited to satisfy a typical search), but if *k* is typically on the order of number of points stored in each leaf node, the performance should be acceptable.

Directly excluding from consideration specific points in the tree is possible, but complicated. When arriving at the initial leaf node, we must make the decisions on whether to descend into a sibling subvolume on our way back towards root, but exclude it from the nearest neighbour consideration. In particular, if all the points in our initial leaf node are excluded from consideration, we must descend into all sibling subvolumes on our way up, until we do have a nearest neighbour candidate.

---

Of these, the variant that retrieves *k* nearest neighbours, seems to me to have the highest potential. (It is quite analogous to the normal exact neighbour search, and with reasonable values of *k* (compared to number of points per leaf node) it should perform at least acceptably -- certainly faster than *k* separate searches on the same dataset.)

I am tempted to consider writing some example code for this, but seeing as I've already made a butt out of myself on this subject, I'm very hesitant.